# Error Processing Large Data With Spark

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am attempting to do a word count using Spark on AWS. I created a spark cluster and I have large files stored in s3. I have a total of 100 files that are 50GB each. I can successfully do a word count on one of these files at a time, but if I try to do them all together it fails. Also, if I try to do a word count on a single file larger than about 60GB it fails. The error I'm getting is:

```
ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor (Executor task launch worker for task 2): Exception in task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.roaringbitmap.RoaringBitmap.runOptimize()Z
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.HighlyCompressedMapStatus$.apply(MapStatus.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.MapStatus$.apply(MapStatus.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here is my word count code

```
public class WordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount").setMaster("local[5]").set("spark.executor.memory","32g");
        JavaSparkContext spark = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Starting word count for {0}", args[0]));
        JavaRDD<String> textFile = spark.textFile(MessageFormat.format("s3a://my_bucket/{0}*", args[0]));
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = textFile.flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")).iterator())
                .mapToPair(word -> new Tuple2<>(word, 1)).reduceByKey((a, b) -> a + b);
        counts.saveAsTextFile(MessageFormat.format("{0}_output", args[0]));

        spark.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I read that this could be a version mismatch error, and I've assured my version of spark in my compiled code and the version of spark on my cluster are the same.

My cluster has 1 master node and 5 core nodes. Each node has 8 cores and 64GB of memory and 1690GB of storage.

To run the code I export the java code above to a jar file. I save the jar file to s3. Then in the AWS console I click "add step" and I select the jar file I uploaded to s3. Then the code is run.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan My spark version is 2.2.1 on the amazon cluster and it's 2.2.1 in the jar that I've uploaded to run the word count. What other jars do you think could be mismatched?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan There is no command. But I added in how I run the code to the question

Comment: then I am not very helpful on that but still I suspect you are running a wrong command when you click run

Comment: This could be caused by conflicts among versions of your dependencies. Try to look for the dependency supplying that class and exclude some transitive dependencies

Comment: Ofc there is a command ! Have you even read the AWS EMR documentation ?

Comment: @eliasah When you say there is a command, what do you mean? A command to do what? There are two ways (that I know of) that I can send my above word count code to the cluster. One way is through the aws console using the "add step" and the other is through the aws command line. Both allow me to point to the jar that contains my code and add arguments. I have not read the entire AWS EMR documentation, but seems like that's my next step.

Answer (score 0):

@ErnestKiwele comment helped me the most. When you go to create a cluster in AWS select the advanced options. By default, Hadoop, Pig, Hive and Hue are selected. I was leaving all of those selected and adding in Spark. When I only use Hadoop and Spark (which is all I need) I no longer receive the error. Must have been some conflict that existed between spark and the others. Thanks!